# Como obter o valor do ID de um button?

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

No ID existe um valor dinâmico, daí gostaria de obter esse valor sem clicar apenas mapear o  botão e armazenar num var:

```
<button name="edit" id="valor_dinamico">Edit</button>
```

Comment: Quantos botões como esses tens? só 1?

Comment: e como vai identificar que é esse botão exatamente que quer saber o id se tiver vários botões na página? vai clicar nele?

Comment: Só com a informação que deu não é possível dar uma resposta que funcione sempre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei se é exatamente isso, mas fazendo um `forEach` vc consegue pegar todos os `ID` de todos os `Buttons` e na para pegar o valor do ID vc usa o `.id` conforme fiz no modelo abaixo.

Vaso queira que o id seja uma variável vc pode armazena-lo com `let idd = e.id` por exemplo. Deixei essa parte comentada no código abaixo, mas o resultado da impressão é o mesmo

```js
function x() {
    let bt = document.querySelectorAll('button');

    bt.forEach((e) => {

        console.log('O ID é: ' + e.id);
        
        //se quiser colocar o ID em uma variável e depois imprimir
        //let idd = e.id 
        //console.log(idd);
    })
}

x()
```

```html
<button id="bt1">btn1</button>
<button id="bt2">btn2</button>
<button id="bt3">btn3</button>
<button id="bt4">btn4</button>
```

Comment: mas nesse caso, como saber que é aquele botão específico?

Comment: @RicardoPontual eu acho que entendi a questão um pouco diferente de vc, pra mim "um botão " seria qualquer botão, ou todos os botões... Já para pegar o botão que ele quer existem mil formas de selecionar, inclusive pelo pai, mas que o pai seja o body. Se vc ver o código ai ele eh bem básico, apenas um exemplo didático... Tentei fazer tbm uma resposta diferente das outras já que o AP não deu muitos detalhes

Comment: eu entendi seu ponto, só fiquei pensando no *"ID de um button?", que nesse caso seria diferente de "todos" os botões, mas enfim acho que isso é por causa de como a pergunta foi escrita, não está bem clara

Answer (score 3):

Pode usar o `querySelector` como mencionado na outra reposta, e selecionar o botão com name "edit":

```js
console.log("id=" + document.querySelector('button[name="edit"]').id)
```

```html
<button name="edit" id="valor_dinamico">Edit</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Para obter o id de forma dinâmica pode ser utilizado o comando abaixo no Javascript:

```
botao = document.querySelector(".classe-pai button")
id = botao.id
```

**id** estará com o valor dessa tag porque foi realizado uma query css que segue a seguinte regra:
Dado um elemento da classe **classe-pai** o filho que seja a primeira tag **button** será selecionada.

As regras de query são as mesmas para a query de css no documento html.

Ou seja, outro exemplo válido seria **#id-do-pai button**

Para saber mais: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp